# How do I convert IP to unicode hex string

Tags: string, python-3.x, hex

How do I go from

```
s = "8.8.8.8"
```

to

```
'\x08\x08\x08\x08'
```

in Python? The same from other IPs such as `192.168.0.1`.

I tried this way.

```
from pysnmp.proto import rfc1902 
str(rfc1902.IpAddress("192.168.0.1"))
```

but I get

```
'\x00\x01'
```

instead of

```
'\xC0\xA8\x00\x01'
```

My final goal is to set this IP via snmp protocol using easysnmp lib.

Comment: There are lots of ways. Why don't you give it a try and then come back once you've written some code that you're having an issue with. First though, you should read [help] and [faq].

Comment: I tried this way.
``

Comment: I tried this way.
`from pysnmp.proto import rfc1902
 str(rfc1902.IpAddress("192.168.0.1"))`
but I get '\x00\x01'' instead of '\xC0\xA8\x00\x01'

Comment: Edit it into the question, don't leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
"".join([chr(int(x)) for x in "8.8.8.8".split(".")])
```